# Uploading speed to Salesforce Marketing Cloud SFTP

Tags: data, cloud, marketing-cloud, sftp

Is there anyway we can increase uploading speed to Salesforce Marketing Cloud SFTP SFTP? Our data size is quite huge and with current speed (maximum 2MB/sec) it's taking quite a lot of time to upload to SFTP daily.

Comment: Have you tried zipping the data files before uploading? The type of files you'll be uploading will be highly compressible and the overhead of unzipping in your automation to ingest the files is very likely far smaller than the time it takes to upload.

Comment: It would also help, that make sure to use light weight files like CSV file, rather than XLX or XLSX which would reduce the file size up to 1:6 times!